# Error with: WooCommerce Avoid add to cart for non logged user

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, cart

I wondered if anyone can help me?

I am  using a Wordpress site with Woocommerce plugin.

I am using a piece of code to avoid adding to cart for non logged in customers which I found on this site, it works great apart from one issue. It doesn't work on the product page. When you click the add to cart button, it doesn't redirect to the custom login page like it does if you press the button on the category view page. Instead the page just refreshes.

I put the code in to the functions.php file. I've then tried putting it into a few other places but that hasn't worked. Could anyone help me with this and let me know if there is another location I should be putting the code in? Thanks in advance, I'd really appreciate the help!

Here's the link to the question and the code is below: [WooCommerce Avoid add to cart for non logged user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246951/woocommerce-avoid-add-to-cart-for-non-logged-user)

```
 // Replacing add-to-cart button in shop pages and archives pages (forn non logged in users)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'conditionally_change_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $link = get_permalink($product_id);
        $button_text = __( "View product", "woocommerce" );
        $html = '<a href="'.$link.'" class="button alt add_to_cart_button">'.$button_text.'</a>';
    }
    return $html;
}

// Avoid add to cart for non logged user (or not registered)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'logged_in_customers_validation', 10, 3 );
function logged_in_customers_validation( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $passed = false;

        // Displaying a custom message
        $message = __("You need to be logged in to be able adding to cart…", "woocommerce");
        $button_link = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );
        $button_text = __("Login or register", "woocommerce");
        $message .= ' <a href="'.$button_link.'" class="login-register button" style="float:right;">'.$button_text.'</a>';

        wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

Comment: `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` should work on the product page also. `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` will work only on shop and archive pages.

Comment: Hi, sorry could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Also, with the code below, do I add that alongside the current code I've used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your function hook for `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` is incorrect. You are using `conditionally_change_loop_add_to_cart_link` rather than `quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link`.

Secondly, your URL for the link is using the current product page ID, which is going to point you at the current product page URL and not another page.

Other than that, you had it mostly correct with `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`.

EDIT:

For product single pages, if you look at `content-single-product.php` in Woocommerce, the action `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` seems to handle what the "add to cart" form looks like. If you'd like to not show the add to cart form, you'll want to first remove the action from the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook.

```
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart',30);
}
```

Then add your own action in at that priority to put in your message:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {
    global $product_id;
    if(!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $message = __("You need to be logged in to be able adding to cart…", "woocommerce");
        $button_link = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );
        $button_text = __("Login or register", "woocommerce");
        $message .= ' <a href="'.$button_link.'" class="login-register button" style="float:right;">'.$button_text.'</a>';
        echo $message;
    }

});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the help, I don't suppose you could clarify the second part? Which link and what should it be?
Appreciate the help!
Thanks,

Comment: Have you had a chance to look and clarify please?

Comment: By the second part, I mean that your code uses `$link = get_permalink($product_id);` where `$product_id` refers to the current product ID and `get_permalink($product_id);` refers you to the URL of the current product page, which the user would already be on. 

You'll want to use `wc_get_page_permalink('my-account')` if you want to have them go to the login page.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, really appreciated. It's working perfectly on the category page but just doesn't seem to work on the product page. I have put the code into the functions.php file and that's where it works for the category. I tried in the content-product.php file but that just through up the error that it's already being done in the functions.php file. What happens is, when on the product page and click to Add to Cart, it just reloads the product page and doesn't redirect to the custom login page like it does when done on the category view. Is there another file it needs to go in?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the single product page. `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` seems to only work on the product archive pages. You'll need to hook into `woocommerce_single_product_summary` on product single pages to modify the content there.  Namely removing the  `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` action from the summary hook and adding in your own content.

Comment: Thank you, you've been a big help. We seem to be getting closer.. It now works to display the login message for non-logged in customers on the product page and works on the category page. But the Add to Cart button now doesn't display on the product page when logged in. Thanls so much for all your help so far.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably because we removed the action. You'll need to conditionally re-add the removed action, or you can wrap the `remove_action` in a `is_user_logged_in` conditional.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it by just adding following code into your active theme function.php file.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','login_before_addtocart');

function login_before_addtocart($price){

if(is_user_logged_in() ){
return $price;
}

else {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

$response .= $price;
$response .= '<br> <a href="' .get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')). '">Login</a> to add product into cart';

return $response;
  }

}
```

[image]

[image]