# Avoid Add To Cart for Non Logged User - When AJAX is activated

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, cart

basically I want to prevent users who are not logged in to not be able to add a product into the cart. When the customer is on the category page and clicks on "add to cart", the page should be refreshed with an error message "Login or Register [..].

I have already looked for some solutions in StackOverflow and could find a good solution using *[WooCommerce Avoid add to cart for non logged user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47246951/woocommerce-avoid-add-to-cart-for-non-logged-user/47250817#47250817)*
*(I only use the second snippet, because I don't want to actually change the Interface/Design)*:

However, when AJAX is activated and the customer clicks on the add to cart (on the category page), the page doesn't refresh with the Error Message - but the customer will be directed to the actual Product Page and then(!) have to click on add to cart again in order to get the error message.

Is there any way to change the code or anything like that, so that clicking on the add to cart button on the category page as an unregistered/unlogged used will refresh the same page with an error message (and not redirect to the product page).

Comment: My guess would be, that the AJAX functionality likely binds itself to the element(s) here based on them having the class `add_to_cart_button`, so I’d simply remove that from the output you are generating there. Then the click on that link should take you to the target page directly, without AJAX interfering. (If removing that class from the element makes it _look_ different now, then adding the missing styling again is probably a lot easier, than trying to interefere with the AJAX cart logic itself.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment - however, i am still quite new to PHP and the functions from wordpress.. Can you explain what do you mean by remove "that" from the output? Should i not return anything? Thanks in advance!